# Expanded widget must be placed inside Flex widget

Tags: flutter

New to flutter. Here is my code. Can someone tell where am I wrong? 
Also, I don't want TextField to be hidden when keyboard appears. Is there any other way to do this other than using KeyboardAvoider?

```
return Scaffold(
        resizetoavoidbottomInsets: true,
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
            Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height), 
          Image.asset('images/otp.jpeg'), 
          Positioned(
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,

              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[

                Text('Welcome), 
                  Spacer(
                    flex: 1,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,

                    child: Form(

                      key: _formKey,
                      child: TextFormField(), 



                    ),
                  ),
                 Spacer()


                ],
              ),
            )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want TextField to be hidden when keyboard appears. Is there
>   any other way to do this other than using KeyboardAvoider?

set the `resizeToAvoidBottomInsets` property on the scaffold to true

as for the title:

> Expanded widget must be placed inside Flex widget

you are putting a `Flex` widget inside a `Widget` that doesn't extent `Flex` (for example `Column` and `Row` extend `Flex`, so you should either remove the `Expanded` or wrap it inside a `Widget` that extends `Flex`

Comment: Actually I think that the problem is that I have set a  container with height equal to screen's height in stack. But if I don't use it, the rest of the content in stack is getting hidden. I don't why this happens.

Comment: Is your code pasted here correctly?I am not able to use it in my IDE

Comment: Sorry I made a silly mistake. Thanks, your answer worked!